# Rails routing file to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my rails app structure as

**TestApp**
| app 
| bin 
| config 
| custom 
 
| db 
| lib 
| log 
| public 
|.... 
|....

I have a static html file in **custom/thankyou.html**

Whenever i render this html file from controller as

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :"custom/thankyou.html", :layout => false, location: params; @is_valid } 
end
```

I want its route to be as http://hostname/thankyou

How to add a route for this?

Comment: You don't need to create a custom directory for your views. This view should go under `app/views/customs` directory. than, you just add a `thankyou` action to `customs` controller. and a route `get '/thankyou', to: 'customs#thankyou'`

Comment: I do not understand how this is a static page and you render it using `render` method. Static pages are html pages that will not get rendered, but instead returned as they are, and they should go under `public/` folder.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, I have a MobileController which has a POST method "taskCompleted", in its response i want to display a html? Still unable to make it work

Comment: Then check this [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage)

Answer (score -1):

Add below route in your route file.

```
get '/thankyou' =>  "custom#thankyou"
```

you can learn more about static page from this link https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages